# Conga Composer Attachment creation Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, attachment, conga, conga-composer

I'm trying to generate a PDF attachment using conga composer and attach it to my custom object.

Find below the apex code used to construct the URL :

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new Map<String, String> {
            'sessionid' => UserInfo.getSessionId(),
            'serverUrl' => Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/Soap/u/22.0/'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
        };
String congaEndpoint='https://Composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html';
String requestURL = congaEndpoint+
            '?SessionId='+parameters.get('sessionid')+
            '&ServerUrl='+parameters.get('serverUrl')+
            '&id='+parentId+
            '&QueryId='+congaQueryId+
            '&DefaultPDF=1'+
            '&TemplateId='+templateId+
            '&SC0=1&SC1=Attachments&AttachmentParentId='+parentId+ 
            '&OFN='+docName+
            '&APIMode=1';
```

Generated URL is working when I am executing it from developer console or using VF-Apex.

**Using lightning component, I'm getting response as [Status=OK, StatusCode=200] but no attachment is created.**

Any help/inputs are appretiable

Thanks,
Shrikant

Comment: were you able to finally resolve this?

Comment: No, I was not. I believe, this is since conga doesn't support attachments in LEX also I've been hearing of attachments will be soon deprecated for LEX. So I suggest using files instead.